# Why am I getting a permission denied error when creating a new .rvmrc file?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 and have installed `rvm` using the standard instructions listed [here](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/) -- this included using rvm to install ruby 1.9.3. Once completed, I ran `rvm use 1.9.3` and then created a gemset titled rails321, set rvm to use 1.9.3 and `gem install rails` into that gemset. Finally, I'm attempting to create an .rvmrc file in a directory with the below, but I'm getting a permission denied error:

[image]

I'm faily new in this environment, so I'd love some help. Thanks :)

Comment: can you please share the output of `ls -l` in that directory (as well as an `ls -l` of the projects directory)?  You can strip out any results in the project directory that do not relate to the simple folder.

Comment: My assumption is that the 'simple' app was created by another user (e.g. root, or untarred with existing permissions intact), so your user may not have permissions to write to that directory.

Comment: Brian...it's weird, but i created the directory `sudo mkdir simple` in the same session...then i changed into it and i didn't have access. you can see in my comment below that by `chmod`ding the directory, i was able to get it to work, but it seems odd to me.

Comment: yep, that's the problem, using sudo in this manner will make the directory owned by root. Try `sudo chown -R tom ~/projects/simple`

Comment: oh ... i see -- thanks, asked this again below...but you've just answered it here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably lack write permissions in `~/projects/simple`. Use `ls -dal . .rvmrc` to check the owner and permission bits of the directory and the file in case it already exists.

Comment: i didn't think to run `sudo chmod 777 simple` on the directory to get permission, but of course after doing this, i was able to run the .rvmrc command above and it created the .rvmrc file. Not sure why the out-of-the-box permissions for my user were so restricted. thanks for your help :)

Comment: There's your problem: The folder is owned by root instead of your. You should not use chmod but chown to make yourself owner of the folder.

Comment: Careful with that, you are exposing yourself to potential security problems.  On your local system, this may be fine - however, you need to be much more cautious in production.  Personally I'd prefer that you `chown -R` to your user account.  `chmod 750` after that if it still doesn't work.  `777` is just asking for trouble (means any body on the system can do whatever they want with your code.

Comment: i can try to use `chown`, but why did `root` own my simple directory, and not my own account? i created it in the terminal with `sudo mkdir simple`? (brian answered this above -- using sudo mkdir makes the dir owned by the root, apparently)

Comment: sudo (with out any qualifiers of a particular user) will run commands as root.

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to get familiar with linux basics.